# Rails object saving to database despite validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an item model and a user_item model.  I have a form for users to create an item.  This form requires a picture but the picture should be used to create a user_item in the user_item database.  The item is saving to the database even though there are errors with the form.

I have it set up so that `item` `has_many` `user_items` and `user_item` `belongs_to` `item`.

**items_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    Item.transaction do

      @item = Item.create(name: item_params[:name],
                                        description: item_params[:description],
                                        tag_list: item_params[:tag_list], 
                                        created_by: current_user.id,
                                        status: Item::STATUS[:pending])

      if item_params[:item] == nil
        @item.errors.add(:picture, "is required")
      end

      if @item.errors.empty?
        @user_item = @item.user_items.build(user_id: current_user.id, picture: item_params[:item][:picture])

        if @user_item.save
          flash[:notice] = "Thank you for submitting your item."
          redirect_to items_path
        else
          render :new
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "UserItem create failed"
        end

      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end



  private
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :tag_list,
                                                                item: :picture)
    end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @item, url: items_path, method: :post, html: { class: "create-item-form" } do |item_builder| %>
  <div class="well">
  <%= item_builder.input :name, required: false, error: false, label: "Item name", input_html: {class: 'form-control'} %>
  <%= item_builder.input :description, as: :text, required: false, error: false, label: "Description of item", input_html: {class: 'form-control'} %>
  <%= item_builder.input :tag_list, required: false, label: "Tags (these will help users find your item)", input_html: {class: 'form-control'} %>
  <%= item_builder.simple_fields_for @item, @item.user_items.build do |user_item_builder| %>
    <%= user_item_builder.input :picture, as: :file, required: false, label: "Picture of you with this item", input_html: {class: 'form-control'} %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= item_builder.submit 'Submit new item', class: "btn btn-primary pull-right inherit-width" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I try submitting the form without a picture and the form renders correctly with an error message but when I check the db, the item is there.  In user_item.rb I have `validates_presence_of :picture`.

I tried to omit code that I didn't think important to my question. If I left something out please let me know.

Comment: Make sure that if item_params[:item] == nil couldn't also be coming through as "" instead of nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` is not invoked when picture is missing.  Change the code to...

```
 if @item.errors.empty?
   @user_item = @item.user_items.build(user_id: current_user.id, picture: item_params[:item][:picture])

   if @user_item.save
     flash[:notice] = "Thank you for submitting your item."
     redirect_to items_path
    else
      render :new
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "UserItem create failed"
    end

  else
    render :new
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "No picture provided"
  end
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!  I am able to do all this without having a `new` action with `@item = Item.new` in this controller.  I thought you needed to when creating a form.  Any idea why I don't need the `new` action?

Comment: because your form explicity states `url: items_path, method: :post,` it doesn't care that @item is nil.  Rails doesn't insist on an action being defined as long as the view exists.

Comment: Would the alternative be to just have `simple_form_for @item` and leave the rest, then I'd have to define the action?

Comment: Yes, that would work.  If the form is shared between `new` and `edit` methods then you'd have to do it that way. As it currently is, the form is only suitable for `new` (post) actions.  If your requiement is only for `new` then what you have is serviceable although a bit unexpected.